# Can I use React icons with Stack Blitz w/o a terminal?

Tags: reactjs

```
/* This is my code below. */


    import React from "react";
    import "./style.css";
    import {FaHome} from 'react-icons/fa';
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div><FaHome /></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

and I get this..

Error in /~/src/App.js (8:14)
Cannot use import statement outside a module.

Imma self learner. So please don't be to harsh. Thanks for any advice or suggestions you have

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
import { FaHome } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaHome";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <FaHome />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear @MasterP. You may accept the answer if resolved your concern to benefit future visitors here